# JavaScript-Pass values between objects

Tags: javascript, object

when I enter at the prompt 0, than I am expecting an alert "stop" but receive "go" instead. Can you help me to get the alert "stop"?

```js
var toyota = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  fuel: 0,
  tank: function(addingfuel) {
    this.fuel = this.fuel + addingfuel;
  },
  start: function() {
    if (this.fuel === 0) {
      alert("stop");
    } else {
      alert("go");
    }
  },
};
var addingfuel = prompt("Please enter fuel added", "liter");
toyota.tank();
toyota.start();
```

Comment: Prompt returns a string. 1,  convert to number: `+addingfuel;` 2. pass it `toyota.tank(+addingfuel);`

Comment: The var addingFuel is completely separate from the parameter function(addingFuel).  Two completely separate unrelated variables that happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine if you change this code

```
this.fuel = this.fuel + addingfuel;
```

to

```
  this.fuel = this.fuel + (addingfuel || 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code a little bit

```
var toyota = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  fuel: 0,
  tank: function(addingfuel) {
    this.fuel = this.fuel + (addingfuel || 0);
  },
  start: function() {
    if (this.fuel === 0) {
      alert("stop");
    } else {
      alert("go");
    }
  },
};
```

**Explanation**
When you pass nothing while calling toyota.tank() this will take argument as undefined and append undefined with a number will give you NaN

```
0 + undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to pass the `addingfuel` with your `tank(addingfuel)` function other wise `addingfuel` contains **undefined** so finally it will show the **go** instead of **stop**.

**N.B** the value of `addingfuel` is **string** so you've to cast it to **integer** like this `parseInt(addingfuel)` otherwise your `this.fuel === 0` condition will fail

Let try this way,

```js
var toyota = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  fuel: 0,
  tank: function(addingfuel) {
    this.fuel = this.fuel + parseInt(addingfuel);
  },
  start: function() {
    if (this.fuel === 0) {
      alert("stop");
    } else {
      alert("go");
    }
  },
};
var addingfuel = prompt("Please enter fuel added", "liter");
toyota.tank(addingfuel); // you need to pass this otherwise it is undefined
toyota.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`window. prompt` returns string type as a return value. That is why  when you adding `fuel` (number) to `addingfuel` (string) it results `"00"` and your condition fails.

In order to overcome this issue, you should cast string to number before working with that value.

```
tank: function(addingfuel) {
  var numberValue = parseFloat(addingfuel, 10);
  numberValue = isNaN(numberValue) ? 0 : numberValue
  this.fuel = this.fuel + numberValue;
}
```

Comment: this.fuel += numberValue;  ;)

Comment: @MrJ Yea, that is better. Thanks